# How to return Modal processing result to Modal

Tags: html, jquery, django, ajax

I want to display the search screen in the modal screen and display the search processing results on that modal screen.
Search result display is completed with modal.
But,In my writing style, when I press the process button in modal, the result is displayed on another screen instead of modal.
What should I do?

I'm using Modal with Ajax in Django.
Ajax is a beginner.

I found this as a result of my research, but it didn't work.

```
<head>
<base target="_self">
</head>
```

Ajax

```
function getCookie(name) {
    var cookieValue = null;
    if (document.cookie && document.cookie !== '') {
        var cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
        for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
            var cookie = jQuery.trim(cookies[i]);
            // Does this cookie string begin with the name we want?
            if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) === (name + '=')) {
            cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
            break;
            }
        }
    }
return cookieValue;
}
var csrftoken = getCookie('csrftoken');
function csrfSafeMethod(method) {
    // these HTTP methods do not require CSRF protection
    return (/^(GET|HEAD|OPTIONS|TRACE)$/.test(method));
}

$.ajaxSetup({
    beforeSend: function (xhr, settings) {
        if (!csrfSafeMethod(settings.type) && !this.crossDomain) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", csrftoken);
        }
    }
});

$(function(){
    $('#edit_foo').on('click', function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var form = $('form')[0];
        var formData = new FormData(form);
        var form = $(this);
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: form.prop("action"),
            data: {
                html: '<form id="form_foo"><input type="submit"></input></form>',
                delay: 1,
                },
        })
            //success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        .done(function(data) {
            $('#foo_modal').find('.modal-body').html(data);
            $('#foo_modal').modal('show');
        })
    });
});
```

modal

```
<div class="modal fade" id="foo_modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">検索</div>
            <div class="modal-body"></div>
            <div class="modal-footer"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

modal-body processing

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ja">

<head>
    <!-- Required meta tags always come first -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>{% block title %}{% endblock %}</title>    
    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet"
    href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        crossorigin="anonymous">  
    {% load bootstrap4 %}
    {% bootstrap_css %}
    {% bootstrap_javascript jquery='full' %}
    {{ filter.form.media }}

</head>

<body class="container">

{% load crispy_forms_tags %}


<div>
    <!--検索条件-->
    <form action="{% url 'storesearch'%}" method="get">
        {{ form2|crispy}}

        <button class="btn btn-primary mt-1" type="submit" id="modal_search">検 索</button>

    </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

As you have experienced, it is cumbersome to achieve this with AJAX. If you want to submit a form that is inside a modal, and you want to display the result in the same modal, it is much easier to use HTMX instead of AJAX: https://htmx.org/

The second code sample on the [introduction page](https://htmx.org/docs/#introduction) does what you want to achieve, in only a few lines of code.